# CSS: Make it possible that element only have differnent :hover background after clicking (:active) on it

Tags: html, css, web

Hi there I try to make it possible that you first need to click on the element and after that it should chang the background everytime you hover over it. Important is that **No JavaScript or JQuery** should be used. **It's not a link** so **:visited** and **href** is not an option

```
*Pseudocode*


 *if* .lst-c:active *than* .lst-c:hover   {
       background: blue;
       border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px !important;
       }
```

Comment: Not possible without Javascript. You can try messing with `<a href="??">` along with `a:visited:hover { background: blue; }`, but that wouldn't really be what you want either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Checkbox Hack

http://timpietrusky.com/advanced-checkbox-hack

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

div {
  background: green;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle-1">Do Something</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div>Control me</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

## Checkbox

```css
/* Hide */
.is {  display: none  }

/* Is checked */
.is:checked + label .content:hover {  background: blue;  }

/* Not checked */
.content:hover {  background: red;  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="is" id="clicker">
<label for="clicker">
  <div class="content">Hello</div>
</label>
```

Comment: While that does will have some effect, it won't have anything like the effect the OP is asking for.

Comment: well the problem is i want that you first need to  click on the item and that it should start hovering, before it should not hover, but thank you for trying to help:)

Comment: Sorry, was working on the checkbox solution. Do you want to be able to unclick it and no longer have it work?